# How can I delete only the last five users of a OU with the command dsrm?

Tags: scripting, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I have to delete only the last five users of a OU using a script with the command dsrm on Windows Server 2016

The only way I found is to add the users manually but I would like to know if it's possible to do it with a command or something (using a script).

This is what I have:

```
dsrm -noprompt -c "cn=rallendem,ou=GruposIvanov,ou=DAMivanov,dc=IvanovD16,dc=local"
dsrm -noprompt -c "cn=mpitarchs,ou=GruposIvanov,ou=DAMivanov,dc=IvanovD16,dc=local"
dsrm -noprompt -c "cn=mrosilloa,ou=GruposIvanov,ou=DAMivanov,dc=IvanovD16,dc=local"
dsrm -noprompt -c "cn=vmanuelp,ou=GruposIvanov,ou=DAMivanov,dc=IvanovD16,dc=local"
dsrm -noprompt -c "cn=vmesasa,ou=GruposIvanov,ou=DAMivanov,dc=IvanovD16,dc=local"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting to do this with dsrm as apposed to the Active Directory PowerShell commands? dsrm is an old tool (server 2008) intended for fixing issues with AD, not for day to day maintenance of users/computers/groups.

Comment: Yes. the reason is because I must do it with DS commands because school says that you have to do it like that.

Comment: Well it sounds like the School doesn't know what they are talking about. DSRM does not provide any way of doing what you are attempting, so you are not going to get anywhere if they insist on it being used.
However, you could do what you are attempting using the Active Directory PowerShell commands, like so: `Get-ADUser -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=the ou to target,DC=your,DC=domain" -Properties whenCreated -Filter * | sort whenCreated -Descending | select -First 5 | Remove-ADUser`